# A custom clustering algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, machine-learning

I have a set of vectors. The vectors are of three different categories viz. A, B and C. Now, I need to cluster these according to the following criteria:

1. There should be a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 3 vectors in each cluster.
2. All the vectors in each cluster should be of a different type. .i.e, a cluster should not contain 2 or more vectors of the same type A, B or C.
3. If here is a cluster containing a set of vectors, then the distance (let's say Eucledian Distance) between any two vectors is less than a pre-defined threshold T.
4. If there is a cluster containing 2 or more vectors (a max of 3 of course), then it is mandatory that one of these vectors is of type A.

Are there any existing algorithms to perform this type of clustering? Suppose I need to do this from scratch, then what steps need to be followed to cluster the vectors according to the above conditions?

Comment: I think you must have an unstated criterion, since you can satisfy the ones given trivially by putting each vector in a separate cluster. Do you just want to minimize the number of clusters? Also, how many vectors total?

Comment: Putting each vector in a different cluster? Can you please clarify that for me please? I have a total of around 5000, 10000 and 12000 vectors of type A, B and C respectively.

Comment: Using the numbers given, your criteria are satisfied by having 27000 clusters. 5000 have a single A, 10000 have a single B, 12000 have a single C.

Comment: If the euclidean distance between a vector of type A and a vector of type B is less than "T", then these two vectors fall under one cluster. So it would then be 26999 clusters. This is what I meant :) (Sorry if didn't express it clearly). The vectors need to be grouped according to their euclidean distance - condition is that if there are 2 or more vectors in a cluster, then there SHOULD be a master vector of type A in the cluster. This master vector is actually in my use-case some kind of a reference/parent vector against which other vectors of type B and C are paired. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this kind of thing using a constraint engine.  something like [choco](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/choco-solver/) includes support for all the constraints you listed (along with optimization since i guess if you have ambiguities you want the smallest number of clusters?).

i'm no expert on choco, but if it's any help i have [notes](http://isti.bitbucket.org/) i made while learning it (those are all on constraint solving, but i got optimisation working last night and will add more soon).  there's a definite learning curve, but for something this complex i don't think it would take you any longer to learn than writing a solution yourself (and then in future you have a new, general tool, rather than a pile of very specific code)

and choco isn't unique - there are a bunch more of these - [google recently packaged some](http://code.google.com/p/or-tools/).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Just another similar simple question:                           If I have a set of vectors, how do I cluster them such that in each cluster, the euclidean distance between any two vectors is less than a threshold? Hence, at the end, there may be vectors that are not part of any cluster. Do you know any existing algorithms for this?